# Simple jquery sum

Tags: jquery, math, sum

I have unknown number of input fields, having class "add" I just wants to sum these with jquery, dont know where I am wrong.

```
<input name="add" class="add" type="text">
<input name="add" class="add" type="text">
<input name="add" class="add" type="text">
<input name="add" class="add" type="text">

<input type="button" value="" onClick="add()" />
```

`

```
function add(){
        val = 0;
        $(".add").each(function() {      
            str = (parseInt(this.value))
            sum=str+str
        });
        alert (sum)
    }
```

`

Comment: +1 for the question for showing just how surprisingly hard it actually is to write a correct answer ;-)

Comment: why i got -2 on my question ?

Comment: @DanishAdeel: Probably lack of basic troubleshooting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're never actually adding stuff into `sum`:

```
function add() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".add").each(function() {   
        sum += +this.value;
    });
    return sum; // an add function shouldn't really "alert"
}
```

If the intention is to only support whole numbers, use `parseInt(this.value, 10)` [note the radix parameter] instead of `+this.value`:

```
function add() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".add").each(function() { 
        var str = this.value.trim();  // .trim() may need a shim
        if (str) {   // don't send blank values to `parseInt`
            sum += parseInt(str, 10);
        }
    });
    return sum;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/eHsJP/

Comment: Ok, this is crazy! =) What does that '+' symbol do exactly? =)

Comment: @benqus it "casts" to a (floating point) number, and converts blank strings to 0 (whereas `parseInt` converts blanks to `NaN`)

Comment: @Alnitak: Mate, your help on the weekend helped me a lot yesterday, thank you again for the brains! =)

Answer (score 4):

```
function add(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(".add").each(function() {
        var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10)
        sum += (!isNaN(val) ? val : 0);
    });
    alert(sum);
}
```

Edit: Sharp eyes, got the parenthesis... =) And the space.

Comment: @DanishAdeel that's half of one of the bugs

Comment: I'll check on your answer mate, that's an interesting one! =)

Comment: @benqus bugs are - 1.  not supplying a radix to `parseInt`, and 2. using   `$(this).value` or `$(this).value()` instead of `$(this).val()` or (better) `this.value`.

Comment: @benqus oh, and 3.  [oops] not checking whether the field even _has_ a value...  `parseInt()` will return `NaN` if the supplied field is blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE8 then you can use the native Javascript `Array.prototype.reduce()` method. You will need to convert your JQuery object into an array first:

```
function add() {
     return $('.add').toArray().reduce(function(sum,element) {
         return sum + Number(element.value);
     }, 0);
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce