# Inputs calculation

Tags: javascript

I have several tables which looks like these below:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 1</a></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sum1" id="sum1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 2</a></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sum2" id="sum2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sum3" id="sum3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td>$total </td>
</tr>
</table>



<table id="table2">
<tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 1</a></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sum1" id="sum1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 2</a></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sum2" id="sum2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sum3" id="sum3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sum4" id="sum4" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td>$total</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Does anybody know if there is a possibility to sum item prices for each input (seperately for table1, table2, etc..)
And at the end print sum of items from all items?

Comment: How can you have items with the same IDs?

Comment: @VisioN it technically doesn't break anything _until_ you try to selector an element by its ID.  It's perfectly possible to write a solution to this problem that doesn't require this, though.

Comment: @Ryszard: Your HTML is invalid. `id` values **must** be unique on the page: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute Your best best is probably just to remove the `id` values from the `input` elements; you don't need them. You can start at the `table` and find all `input` elements with a given name or class. (Note that it's perfectly fine to have multiple `input` elements with the same **`name`**.)

Comment: I've copied table1 as table2 but I forgot to change id's You have right it should be sum4, sum5, etc in second table ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a dom manipulator like jQuery or simply javascript.  I'd give the fields a class to make it even easier--say, "sum".  Then you can grab all the children "sum"s from the parent tables. Parse their value to an int and add.  Not too bad.

[Here's a working JS fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kJX5b/13/)

Comment: I know that I want too much, but are You able to give some tips or exemples, I've tried to google it, and i saw similar solutions based on jQuery and Mootools, but unfortunately im not familiar with JavaScript :(

Comment: @RyszardS. if you don't mind using jQuery, see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563541/simple-jquery-sum/10563597#10563597

Comment: @RyszardS. I've added a link in my answer to a working example I did in jsFiddle. It uses jQuery as the DOM manipulator.

Answer (score 0):

this should be pretty easy with jquery, assuming you can add a class name called "line-item" or something to each input and a class name "total" to the cell which should display calculated sum, you can do

```
function calculateSum(tableId){
 var sum = 0;
 $(tableId + ' .line-item').each(function(){
   var value = parseFloat($(this).val().trim());
   if(value){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
   }
 });
 $(tableId + ' .total').html(sum);
}
```

and invoke this function with the id of the table for which you want.

If you cannot add a class name, this don't get tuffer even a single bit, but instead of `.line-item` try to put just `input`, it should do the trick in this scenario. Instead of .total you can write `tr:last-child td:nth-child(2)`

UPDATE: added "parseInt" to avoid string concatenation

Comment: The OP never mentioned jQuery.  Also your code will produce a concatenated string, not an accumulated sum.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563541/simple-jquery-sum/10563597#10563597

Comment: @Ainitak good point with string concatenation :) However I consider your point about jQuery invalid - the question was about solution and mine was in jquery

Comment: consider yourself lucky - at peak times responses that give a jQuery answer when not specifically requested get mass downvoted.. ;-)

Comment: BTW - read the answer I posted the link to - you've still got some outstanding bugs in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is not to call different elements with similar IDs, it's invalid way. But even if so - you can perform calculations for every table simply working with inputs in this table.

Algorithm:

1. You run loop for all <table> tags.
2. For every <table> tag you find all <input>s (no matter what IDs they have);
3. Calculate total sum for all inputs for current table.

You can do this with JavaScript but better for you is jQuery.

BUT: don't call HTML DOM elements with similar IDs. It's wrong!!!